# Why does "for(;i<=10;i++)" work but "for(i=0;i<=10;;)" doesn't?

Tags: c, for-loop, expression

Why does the first program below work but the second doesn't? I mean, the second program gives an error

> "expected expression before ';'"

But why then it doesn't give the same for **"for(;i<=10;i++)"** as there too the first expression is missing? Doesn't the **";;"** in **"for(i=0;i<=10;;)"** of the second program signify a blank expression? And finally, why **"for(i=0;i<=10;)"** works then upon removing the second semicolon?

```
//Program 1
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i=1;
for(;i<=10;i++)
{
printf("%d\n",i);
}
}

//Program 2
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i;
//for(i=1;i<=10;) // This works but following doesn't
for(i=1;i<=10;;) 
{
printf("%d\n",i);
i++;
}
}
```

Comment: *Count the semicolons and you'll see / **two** is not the same as **three**.*

Comment: semicolon(;) does NOT signify a blank expression.It seperates the 3 expressions inside the for loop.A for loop contains 2 semicolons

Answer (score 12):

`for(i=1;i<=10;;)` is not a valid C syntax. `for` loop syntax in C is

```
for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

Note that, *two semicolons must always be present, even when we've omitted some of the expressions.*

Comment: Only two semicolons go inside the for statement.

Comment: But why the others mentioned are? I would appreciate if you can add some rigorous explanation, even though I am tempted to note down what you said as a rule.

Comment: Could you rephrase your words please?

Comment: @Meathead if you want a "rigorous"  explanation you would usually add a [language lawyer tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer).

Answer (score 4):

A `for` statement cycle consists of three clauses separated by semicolons. Thus it should only have two semi colons and the third one leads to a syntax error. The three sections have the following meaning:

- variable initialization - executed only once before the first iteration
- condition for the cycle - executed after before each iteration to verify if the cycle should break its execution
- step - executed before the check of the condition after each iteration

Each of these steps may be empty but even **exactly two semicolons** should separate the sections.

Answer (score 2):

The "for" structure is set up to have 3 parts:- instantiate variable to iterate on, how long to iterate, and updating the variable (increment, decrement or otherwise).

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

So when you have the below loop,you have 4 parts and this is not valid syntax for the "for" loop.(the parts are separated by the semi colon.)  The other is wrong but syntactically correct because it has 3 sections.

```
for(i=1;i<=10;;)
```

Comment: 'increment the variable' part is obviously incomplete. you can increment, decrement, anything you want with the variable in 3rd part. use 'update' instead for preventing confusions.

Answer (score 2):

For loop contains three conditions

> - Initialization,
> - Condition for iteration,
> - Increment.

The first condition can be also  declared before for loop  like

```
Int i=0;                       
for(;i<10;i++)
{             
}
```

The incremental can also be declared in the loop

```
for(i=0;i<10;)              
{                 
      i++;             
}
```

The condition for iteration should be for sure in the loop.
But your loop contains syntax as if four conditions(3 semicolons). So it is not recognized by C compiler. If you remove extra semicolon it would work.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a syntax error.

The correct C syntax is:

```
 for( exp11, .., exp1N; exp21, .., exp2N ; exp31, .., exp3N) { }
```